# Wrapper fijo con un tamaño en especifico

Tags: html, css, html5

me gustaría saber con que atributos para mi hoja de estilo css podría hacer que el wrapper se mantenga estático, osea con un tamaño en especifico, por ejemplo me pasa que el tamaño de mi wrapper depende de el contenido que tenga mi main, por lo tanto si solo tengo poco contenido el tamaño del wrapper es del tamaño de lo que contiene y a mi me gustaría que tuviese un largo definido.

```
#wrapper { 
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
background-color: #FFFFFF;}
```

Estos son los atributos que uso, gracias ^^.

Comment: Tu `wrapper` tiene que ser un elemento `block` con un `width` y un `height` definidos. Puedes darle `overflow:scroll` para el caso en el cual el contenido es más alto que la caja. Me habría gustado ver un ejemplo funcional con el html y el css correspondiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es difícil sin ver tu código, pero simplemente asigna un tamaño fijo al wrapper.
En este ejemplo te muestro como establecer el tamaño fijo, hice 2, un wrapper y wrapper-auto, el segundo añade un scroll si el contenido sobrepasa el tamaño del wapper.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#wrapper-auto {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.nada {
  margin: 128px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<p>Texo de relleno, texto de relleno Texo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenotexto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenotexto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de relleno</p>
</div>
<div class="nada"></div>
<div id="wrapper-auto">
<p>Texo de relleno, texto de relleno Texo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenotexto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenotexto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de rellenoTexo de relleno, texto de relleno</p>
</div>
```